# Effective way to join tables by range using impala

Tags: sql, hive, between, impala

I have the following tables the first (`Range`) includes range of values and additional columns:

```
row  | From   |  To     | Country ....
-----|--------|---------|---------
1    | 1200   |   1500  |
2    | 2200   |   2700  |
3    | 1700   |   1900  |
4    | 2100   |   2150  |
...
```

The `From` and `To`are `bigint` and are exclusive. The `Range` table includes 1.8M records.
Additional table (`Values`) contains 2.7M records and looks like:

```
 row     | Value  | More columns....
 --------|--------|----------------
    1    | 1777   |    
    2    | 2122   |    
    3    | 1832   |    
    4    | 1340   |    
    ...
```

I would like to create one table as followed:

```
row      | Value  | From   | To    | More columns....
 --------|--------|--------|-------|---
    1    | 1777   | 1700   | 1900  |
    2    | 2122   | 2100   | 2150  |   
    3    | 1832   | 1700   | 1900  |   
    4    | 1340   | 1200   | 1500  |   
    ...
```

I used `BETWEEN` for the above task, but the query never ends:

```
VALUES.VALUE between RANGE.FROM and RANGE.TO
```

Is there a change I need to do in table partitions or in Impala?

Comment: Is it part of "use as many keywords as possible for tables definition" challenge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea of the following solution is to replace a theta join (non-equi join) with an equi join that will lead to a good distribution + efficient local join algorithm.

The range (-infinity,infinity) is being split to section of `n` length.
Each range from the ranges table is being associated with the sections it intersects.

e.g. given n=1000, the range `[1652,3701]` will be associated with the sections `[1000,2000)`, `[2000,3000)` and `[3000,4000)` (and will have 3 records, 1 for each section)

```
               1652              3701
               |                 |
               -------------------

-------------------------------------------------------
|        |        |        |        |        |                
0        1000     2000     3000     4000     5000
```

In the same manner a value from the values table is being associated to the range that contains it, e.g. `2093` will be associated with the range `[2000,3000)`.

The join between the 2 tables is going to be on the value that represents the section, e.g. `[1652,3701]` and `2093` are going to be joined on the section `[2000,3000)`

---

```
create table val_range (id int,from_val bigint,to_val bigint);

insert into val_range values
    (1,1200,1500)
   ,(2,2200,2700)
   ,(3,1700,1900)
   ,(4,2100,2150)
;   

create table val (id int,val bigint);

insert into val values
    (1,1777)    
   ,(2,2122)    
   ,(3,1832)    
   ,(4,1340)
;
```

---

```
set n=1000;

select      v.id
           ,v.val
           ,r.from_val
           ,r.to_val

from       (select  r.*
                   ,floor(from_val/${hiveconf:n}) + pe.i    as match_val

            from    val_range r
                    lateral view    posexplode
                                    (
                                        split
                                        (
                                            space
                                            (
                                                cast
                                                (
                                                    floor(to_val/${hiveconf:n}) 
                                                  - floor(from_val/${hiveconf:n}) 

                                                    as int
                                                )
                                            )
                                           ,' '
                                        )
                                    ) pe as i,x
            ) r

            join    val v

            on      floor(v.val/${hiveconf:n})    =
                    r.match_val

where       v.val between r.from_val and r.to_val

order by    v.id        
;
```

---

```
+------+-------+------------+----------+
| v.id | v.val | r.from_val | r.to_val |
+------+-------+------------+----------+
|    1 |  1777 |       1700 |     1900 |
|    2 |  2122 |       2100 |     2150 |
|    3 |  1832 |       1700 |     1900 |
|    4 |  1340 |       1200 |     1500 |
+------+-------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks Dudu! Can you please add a bit explanation to your great solution?

Comment: I will, but you should know that this is a solution for Hive

Comment: Thanks, I saw it. I can work either with Hive or Impala. Impala is preferable, but if it works in Hive only I'll use it in Hive.

Comment: Hi Avi, did it work for you? can you share some execution metrics?

Comment: Thanks Dudu! You are an expert! It worked!!! I'll try to see if I can rerun and have the metrics.

Comment: Hi Dudu, the elapsed time for the above mentioned tables using the query took about 1.5 minutes.

Comment: Real data? 1.8M & 2.7M?

Comment: YES, real data! U R EXPERT!

Comment: Great! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into a similar problem with IP addresses and GeoIP database. Range joins were prohibitingly slow, but joining through "buckets", and then refining with a range condition (where) did the trick.

```sql
select
    g.country_iso_code,
    count(1) as cnt
from access_log as a
join geoip as g
  -- number of IPv4 addresses: 2**32 ==> 10 digits
  -- max network size: 2**23 ==> 8.3M ==> 7 digits 
  --   check with: select max(net_end-net_start) from geoip
  on round(a.int_ip, -7) = round(g.net_start, -7) -- <<== Step 1. bucket IP addresses
where a.date between "2021-12-01" and "2021-12-31"
  and a.int_ip between g.net_start and g.net_end  -- <<== Step 2. refine
group by g.country_iso_code
order by cnt desc
```

`int_ip` is IPv4 IP addresses converted into integer numbers. E.g. 192.168.1.1 is 3232235777. `net_start` and `net_end` is represented similarly.

If some inaccuracy is allowed, then you may reduce the rounding to -6, -5, ... digits, which will speed up execution, but large networks may be miscategorized.