# Reduction in the number of records using range join

Tags: join, hive, left-join, between, impala

Following the [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384401/effective-way-to-join-tables-by-range-using-impala)
I have the following tables the first (Range) includes range of values and additional columns:

```
row  | From   |  To     | Country ....
-----|--------|---------|---------
1    | 1200   |   1500  |
2    | 2200   |   2700  |
3    | 1700   |   1900  |
4    | 2100   |   2150  |
...
```

The `From` and `To` are bigint and are exclusive. The Range table includes 1.8M records. Additional table (Values) contains 2.7M records and looks like:

```
 row     | Value  | More columns....
 --------|--------|----------------
    1    | 1777   |    
    2    | 2122   |    
    3    | 1832   |    
    4    | 1340   |    
    ...
```

I would like to create one table as followed:

```
row      | Value  | From   | To    | More columns....
 --------|--------|--------|-------|---
    1    | 1777   | 1700   | 1900  |
    2    | 2122   | 2100   | 2150  |   
    3    | 1832   | 1700   | 1900  |   
    4    | 1340   | 1200   | 1500  |   
    ...
```

I used the left outer join in the following code:

```
set n=1000;

select      v.id
           ,v.val
           ,r.from_val
           ,r.to_val

from      val v
        left outer join    

 (select  r.*
                   ,floor(from_val/${hiveconf:n}) + pe.i    as match_val

            from    val_range r
                    lateral view    posexplode
                                    (
                                        split
                                        (
                                            space
                                            (
                                                cast
                                                (
                                                    floor(to_val/${hiveconf:n}) 
                                                  - floor(from_val/${hiveconf:n}) 

                                                    as int
                                                )
                                            )
                                           ,' '
                                        )
                                    ) pe as i,x
            ) r



            on      floor(v.val/${hiveconf:n})    =
                    r.match_val

where       v.val between r.from_val and r.to_val

order by    v.id       
;
```

However there is a vast reduction in the number of records of the new table ~31k records out of 2.7M. How can it be if I use the `left outer join`? How can I fix it?

Comment: Good morning Avi :-) There is a filtering on `r` (`v.val between r.from_val and r.to_val`) which actually cancels the functionality of the LEFT JOIN and turn it into a INNER JOIN and apparently not all the values are covered by ranges.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I use the functionality of Left Join? the between is essential since it determines the required range to the the relevant value? I wouldn't like to omit values that have no range.

Comment: I'm assuming v.id is unique?

Comment: Practically there is no v.id so can we might use the row number as a unique key instead?

Comment: It will work for relatively small set of data. For large sets take look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974548/how-to-add-an-integer-unique-id-to-query-results-efficiently

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you explain why the answer is relevant for small datasets only? And is there a way to use row_id instead of v_id and r_id in case I don't have a unique key for both tables?

Comment: (1) `v.id` could be any unique value for that matter. (2) Absurdly, while Hadoop won data sorting contests starting in 2008 (http://sortbenchmark.org/), In hive there is still no implementation of distributed sorting ,which mean all sorting operations are done on a single node. That goes for the ORDER BY clause of a query as well as for ORDER BY clause of windows functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have a `v.id`

```
set n=1000;

select      v.id
           ,r.from_val
           ,r.to_val

from                    val     v 

            left join  (select      v.id
                                   ,r.from_val
                                   ,r.to_val

                        from                val     v 

                                    join    (...)   r 

                                    on      floor(v.val/${hiveconf:n})    =
                                            r.match_val

                        where       v.val between r.from_val and r.to_val
                        ) r

            on          r.id    =
                        v.id

order by    v.id
```

**As for the OP request, here is the full query:**

```
set n=1000;

select      v.id
           ,r.from_val
           ,r.to_val

from                    val     v 

            left join  (select      v.id
                                   ,r.from_val
                                   ,r.to_val

                        from                val     v 

                                    join   (select  r.*
                                                   ,floor(from_val/${hiveconf:n}) + pe.i    as match_val

                                            from    val_range r
                                                    lateral view    posexplode
                                                                    (
                                                                        split
                                                                        (
                                                                            space
                                                                            (
                                                                                cast
                                                                                (
                                                                                    floor(to_val/${hiveconf:n}) 
                                                                                  - floor(from_val/${hiveconf:n}) 

                                                                                    as int
                                                                                )
                                                                            )
                                                                           ,' '
                                                                        )
                                                                    ) pe as i,x
                                            ) r

                                    on      floor(v.val/${hiveconf:n})    =
                                            r.match_val

                        where       v.val between r.from_val and r.to_val
                        ) r

            on          r.id    =
                        v.id

order by    v.id
```

Comment: Dear @Dudu Markovitz, could you please fill in the join (...). I think there is twice alias for r. In addition, can you please explain why you added r.id = v.id? Since even I add the row number as unique id for each table they are not supposed to be equal? Thank you very much.

Comment: Added. There is no problem with reusing aliases in different scopes. `r.id` is actually `v.id`in a sub-query aliased by `r`