# Finding efficiently all relevant sub ranges for bigdata tables in Hive/ Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, range, bigdata

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44403489/reduction-in-the-number-of-records-using-range-join) question, I would like to ask.
I have 2 tables:
The first table - `MajorRange`

```
row  | From   |  To     | Group ....
-----|--------|---------|---------
1    | 1200   |   1500  | A
2    | 2200   |   2700  | B
3    | 1700   |   1900  | C
4    | 2100   |   2150  | D
...
```

The second table - `SubRange`

```
row  | From   |  To     | Group ....
-----|--------|---------|---------
1    | 1208   |   1300  | E
2    | 1400   |   1600  | F
3    | 1700   |   2100  | G
4    | 2100   |   2500  | H
...
```

The output table should be the all the `SubRange` groups who has overlap over the `MajorRange` groups. In the following example the result table is:

```
 row | Major  |  Sub | 
-----|--------|------|-
1    | A      |   E  | 
2    | A      |   F  |
3    | B      |   H  |
4    | C      |   G  |
5    | D      |   H  |
```

In case there is no overlapping between the ranges the `Major` will not appear.
Both tables are big data tables.How can I do it using Hive/ Spark in most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `spark`, maybe a non equi join like this?

```
val join_expr = major_range("From") < sub_range("To") && major_range("To") > sub_range("From")

(major_range.join(sub_range, join_expr)
 .select(
    monotonically_increasing_id().as("row"), 
    major_range("Group").as("Major"), 
    sub_range("Group").as("Sub")
  )
).show

+---+-----+---+
|row|Major|Sub|
+---+-----+---+
|  0|    A|  E|
|  1|    A|  F|
|  2|    B|  H|
|  3|    C|  G|
|  4|    D|  H|
+---+-----+---+
```

Comment: Thanks, in case there is no row column. What do I have to change in your code?

Comment: You don't need to change the code. The `row` column is not used here. I created a new `row` column to meet your output.