# Finding relevant sub ranges for bigdata tables in MS SQL RDBMS efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, range

Following my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183563/finding-efficiently-all-relevant-sub-ranges-for-bigdata-tables-in-hive-spark).
I have MS SQL Server (regular SQL) that holds 2 tables. Each table contains ~500,000 records. When I write this query it stacks. How can I make it run in efficient way?
Here are the tables: 
The first table - `MajorRange`

```
| From   |  To     | Group ....
|--------|---------|---------
| 1200   |   1500  | A
| 2200   |   2700  | B
| 1700   |   1900  | C
| 2100   |   2150  | D
...
```

The second table - `SubRange`

```
  | From   |  To     | Group ....
  |--------|---------|---------
  | 1208   |   1300  | E
  | 1400   |   1600  | F
  | 1700   |   2100  | G
  | 2100   |   2500  | H
    ...
```

The output table should be the all the `SubRange` groups who has overlap over the `MajorRange` groups. In the following example the result table is:

```
| Major  |  Sub | 
|--------|------|-
| A      |   E  | 
| A      |   F  |
| B      |   H  |
| C      |   G  |
| D      |   H  |
```

The query I used is something like:

```
select M.Group Major , S.Group Sub 
From MajorRange M, SubRange S
where M.From <= S.To and M.To >= S.From
```

Comment: select M.Group Major , S.Group Sub 
From MajorRange M INNER JOIN  SubRange S
ON M.From <= S.To and M.To >= S.From. Have you tried properly joining your tables ?

Comment: Are there any indexes? If no indexes are defined you are forcing  500000*500000 cycles.